# Error Reading File <path>: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen <path

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using windows 10 and I keep having this issue using jekyll. Seems to be an ongoing issue in the jekyll community but I cant find an answer to fix. Has anyone found any good fixes for this? Edit: I am also using Jekyll 3.3.0

repo - https://github.com/dkbollig/Drago-CMS

```
[12:22:19] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
Configuration file: C:/repo/drago-cms/_config.yml
        Source: C:/repo/drago-cms
   Destination: C:/repo/drago-cms/_site
Incremental build: enabled
  Generating...
Error reading file C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/compress.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/compress.html
Error reading file C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/default.html
Error reading file C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/index.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/index.html
Error reading file C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/page.html
Error reading file C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/post.html
```

Thanks!

Derek

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you post the full message as text ?

Comment: I've seen this error caused a few ways, could be clashing permalinks or the mismatched casing in the message. If you provide a repo URL it's easier to debug.

Comment: Hey @RossPhillips updated with the git repo. I had this happen on two different window machines using the repo but I checked it on a macbook and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Potential fixes:**

- https://github.com/dkbollig/Drago-CMS/blob/master/_layouts/default.html has invalid front matter (the HTML comment is not allowed in YAML).
- Disabling (setting to `false`) the experimental `incremental` flag in your `_config.yml`.
- Remove `_layouts/compress.html` and references to it.
- Check the Jekyll version matches the requirement for this boilerplate.

These files and settings might reveal the true error, but the error message you have already seems to be referencing a bad path from somewhere:

```
C:/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/post.html
C:/repo/Drago-CMS/repo/drago-cms/_layouts/post.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. When in the command line i used the cd command like this

```
cd repo/projectname --> doesn't work
```

My actual folder name is "ProjectName". The jekyll command is case letter sensitive and wouldn't work if it wasn't exactly the same.

```
cd repo/ProjectName --> works
```